# How to add quotation marks to key-value object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, key-value

How can I change this :

```
{"position":4}
```

to this :

```
{"position":"4"}
```

Is there any simpe function (in javascript or node.js package), that puts quots around value ?

Comment: Oboy, is it a string, array, object, json, superman? `string.replace('4', '"4"');` ???

Comment: It is object which came out of JSON.parse(). I cannot just replace 4 with "4", because it can be arbitrary string.

Comment: You can if you iterate the object with `for (key in obj)` and check the typeof etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this (add quotation marks to the string):

```
var obj = {position: 4};
for (var p in obj)
    obj[p] = '"' + obj[p] + '"';
```

Or this (convert number to string):

```
var obj = {position: 4};
for (var p in obj)
    obj[p] = obj[p].toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

i go whith `4+""` as that castes it to a string.

but you probly wanner rethink Why you need to cast your number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any function as such but you may do it with something like:

EDIT: 
If you don't know the property value, do like this:

```
var test=new Object();
test.position="4";
for (var prop in test) {
    test[prop]="\""+test[prop]+"\"";
      alert(prop + " = " + test[prop]);
   }
```

Check updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js6SB/3/)

Comment: Problem is I don't know it would be 'position', it can be whatever other string. :-(

Comment: see my edit which demonstrates how to loop through a object and changing their value